# Range Slider Nuxt JS

Tags: slider, range, nuxtjs

So I have a task, I need to build a calculator  based on a range slider in Nuxt that changes the color when the thumb moves and it calculates something at the same time. I've managed to get it to work on a certain level. But when I flip pages, it crashes saying that can't read addEventListener of undefined.

here is the code:

```
  <div class="range">
<input  v-html="amount" v-model="value" type="range" class="slider" id="amount"  min="0" max="100">
    </div>
     

methods: {
colorSlider(){
const slider = document.querySelector('#amount')
let x = slider.value 
let color = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(249,84,78)' + x+ '%, rgb(224,224,224)' + x +'%)'
slider.style.background=color
}
},
mounted(){
document.querySelector('#amount').addEventListener('mousemove',this.colorSlider)
}
```

Any ideeas ?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need an event listener— Vue is reactive, simply tying the slider to a data property via v-model is fine.

Eg:

```
...
<input type="range" v-model="sliderValue">
...

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      sliderValue: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you adjust the slider, the value of `sliderValue` will update. No event listener required.

To use the value of `sliderValue` for something useful in your template— you should use a computed property, not a method.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      sliderValue: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sliderBgColor() {
      return `linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(249,84,78) ${this.sliderValue}%, rgb(224,224,224) ${this.sliderValue}%)`
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you adjust the slider, the data property it’s tied to (sliderValue) via v-model will change. The computed property sliderBgColor notices the change and automatically updated it’s return value. Use the return value of sliderBgColor in your input and you’re done.

```
<input type="range" v-model="sliderValue" :style="`background: ${sliderBgColor}`"
```

There’s plenty of information available on computed properties, I’d recommend taking a look at the Vue docs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Works like a charm.